# Sql query on restricting decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to consider a decimal only upto first decimal.
for eg. 24.816 ,, 24.8,, 24.83
I want to compare all three values only by detecting 24.8(that is first point decimal of all three values)
How can I limit my values upto first decimal place.

Comment: So you don't want to round?  You want to treat 24.7999 as 24.7?

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the truncate() function :

```
select cast((24.79-(24.79%.1)) as decimal (18,1))
```

it returns 24.7

Comment: If its something like 24.87642...then?

Comment: Just replace 24.79 by 24.87642.., it will return 24.8. You can try here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db4b1f5dafc6403926c0c2ddeb6ba665

Answer (score 1):

You need the function [`TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):
`TRUNCATE(24.816, 1)`, `TRUNCATE(24.8, 1)` and `TRUNCATE(24.83, 1)` all return `24.8`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13896a9029f9c557da5705943fb3ff8d).

The 2nd argument of `TRUNCATE()` (if positive) is the number of decimal places that you want to keep.

Comment: Any other way apart from trunc function?

Comment: @AmanThakur why? What is the problem with this function?

Comment: I was just trying to use this without the usage of a function

Comment: @AmanThakur functions like TRUNCATE() save you from the trouble to deal with complex mathematical calculations.

Comment: Cant we do something like something by substring?

Comment: @AmanThakur yes, but then you will need to convert the number to a string, use at least 2 functions to extract the part of the string that you want and finally convert back to a number.

Comment: You can use a truncate by hand expression kind of  `col * 10 div 1 / 10` instead of `truncate(col,1)`  Don't know how it's better.

Comment: @Serg as I mentioned in one of my previous comments it can be done with math calculations. My question is why not use a function that is specifically created to solve this requirement.

Comment: @forpas,  exactly. I see no advantages too.